# How do I enable warning C6244 in MSVC++?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings

I'd like to enable the warning for ["Variable name hiding"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/35whedce.aspx) as an error in MSVC++, so that things like this will be flagged as an error:

```
class A
{
    int var ;
    A()
    {
      int var = 5 ; // HIDING: want this to be an error
    }
} ;
```

Comment: To even enable the 6000 series warnings, you have to [perform this procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10163994/111307).

Answer (score 4):

You can use pragma directives:

```
#pragma warning(error: 6244)

class A
{
    int var ;
    A()
    {
      int var = 5 ; // HIDING: want this to be an error
    }
} ;
```

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko my crystal globe told me to read the title. :)

Comment: Actually I prefer this way, but unfortunately may have the ["include order" problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7082265/what-is-the-first-line-of-code-that-will-be-compiled).  Hence my selection of [the project setting answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10157047/111307) as the accepted one

Answer (score 1):

for Visual Studio 2010 goto "Project Properties -> C/C++ -> Advanced"

[image]

Comment: So, this doesn't actually work.  I still don't know how to [enable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151908/enable-a-single-warning-in-visual-studio) 6000* series warnings

Comment: Ok, now I know [how to enable the 6000 series warnings](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10163994/111307).

Answer (score 0):

there is a **treat specific warning as error** on the **advanced** tab of the **C++ property** pages of your project setting

Comment: How would disabling the warning make the compiler treat it as an error?

Comment: Are you sure? I can't find it. I see the **disable specific warnings** tab, but that's it.

Comment: I have it as the last option (MSVC c++11 ,but there is one in MSVC 2010 too but maybe it's somewhere else)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `/we` compiler option to turn a particular error into a warning.  For example, `/we6244` will make warning C6244 an error.  See [the documentation for the `/w` option and its friends for details.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/thxezb7y%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)