# How do I enable the 6000 series warnings (code analysis warnings) in MSVC++?

Tags: visual-c++, compiler-warnings

Even warning level 4 and "all warnings" does not make the [6000 series](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a5b9aa09.aspx) warnings appear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually enabling these "Code Analysis" warnings has it's own dialog.

In your project properties, you must check "Enable Code Analysis on Build" to make it work.

[image: code analysis]

This code should then show error 6246:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int x ;

  {
    int x = 6 ;
    printf( "%d\n", x ) ;
  }

}
```

> warning C6246: Local declaration of 'x' hides declaration of the same name in outer scope.

This setting appears to be completely independent of the "Configuration Properties/C/C++/General/Warning Level" setting in the properties dialog.

[image: setting doesnt matter]